# Array constant in SUMPRODUCT() in Excel

Tags: excel-formula, sumproduct

I want to sum values in a column when it matches at the same time one of many values in another column:

```
4   S
1   -
2   M
```

I want to sum values in A only if corresponding value in B contain "S" or "M", but following command:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B1:B3={"S";"M"}); A1:A3)
```

but it returns a value error. I would expect 6 to be returned.

It only works if I put one value in the array constant (`{"S"}`).

Any way to fix this?

Comment: Do you have many criteria? or just the two, `S` and `M`?

Comment: @BigBen I only got five

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option - use SUM and SUMIF, e.g.

```
=SUM(SUMIF(B1:B6,{"S","M","X","Y","Z"},A1:A6))
```

[image]

This is an array formula so depending on your version of Excel you may need to confirm with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.